# Google Pay Integration in android App (Restricted Countries)

Tags: java, android, google-pay

I am implementing Google Pay in android app but my country is restricted so I can't perform even test transaction. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to create a new Google account for a different country to try it out?

Comment: @Soc No, because it requires phone number authentication.

Comment: When I create an account with [this link](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/), I get this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGpAx.png). The phone number is optional for me. I don't know if this is the case world-wide, but works for me in the US.

Comment: @Soc Yes, I created account without phone number but it does not specify the country for my email.

Comment: Can you try to change your country in the [Google Pay settings](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644076?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, I changed it, now it belongs to US

Comment: Can you confirm if it solved your problem?

Comment: I am adding a test card number for payment but getting Transaction declined: invalid payment method Learn more [OR-CCSEH-05]

Comment: The problem appears to still be country related. Do you get the same issue with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f70e8nx4/)? If not, can you create a reproduction scenario with the JSFiddle? Alternatively, contact support using http://pay.google.com/business/console